# valueUpdate afterkeydown not working with observable array

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am working on a project where the user can add or remove "assets". The assets are stored in an observable array and displayed as DIVs on the page. Each asset DIV can be dragged and resized, using jQuery.

I have 4 text inputs, one for width, height, top and left, that relate to the DIVs size and position:

```html
<label for="asset-position-top">Top:</label>
<input type="text" name="asset-position-top" value="0" size="6" id="editor-assetTop" data-bind="valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', value: assets()[selectedIndex()].top"/>
<br />

<label for="asset-position-left">Left:</label> 
<input type="text" name="asset-position-Left" value="0" size="6" id="editor-assetLeft" data-bind="value: assets()[selectedIndex()].left, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"/>
<br />

<label for="asset-size-width">Width:</label> 
<input type="text" name="asset-size-width" value="0" size="6" id="editor-assetWidth" data-bind="value: assets()[selectedIndex()].width, valueUpdate: ['afterkeydown', 'input']" />
<br />

<label for="asset-size-height">Height:</label> 
<input type="text" name="asset-size-height" value="0" size="6" id="editor-assetHeight" data-bind="valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', value: assets()[selectedIndex()].height" />
```

The text inputs are binded to the values of the asset in the array, and the array is also updated via JQuery when the DIV is resized or moved:

```js
$(element).draggable({
    drag: function() {
        // ADD DRAG UPDATE HERE
        var position = $(this).position();
        viewModel.assets()[viewModel.selectedIndex()].top = position.top;
        viewModel.assets()[viewModel.selectedIndex()].left = position.left;
    }
}).resizable({
    resize: function() {
        // ADD RESIZE UPDATE HERE   
        viewModel.assets()[viewModel.selectedIndex()].width = $(this).width();
        viewModel.assets()[viewModel.selectedIndex()].height = $(this).height();
    }
})
```

Everything works fine, however when the user changes the values in the text box I want to DIV to change instantly. After looking around I saw many examples that use the valueUpdate property. I tried using it (and with several variations) but still the DIV is only updated when I click out of the div.

I created a jsFiddle to show what I am doing and that it is NOT working: http://jsfiddle.net/bu3sD/2/

(Here is an example I found that DOES work and what I am trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/fgpJn/ )

I really hope someone can explain to me what I am doing wrong!

Comment: Is your JSFiddle example correct?

Comment: The JSFiddle is showing my current code with the problem. I am trying to understand why my code does not work like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fgpJn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because after you create a new asset, you're overwriting your observables with plain values:

```
self.addAsset = function(type, element, cssClass){
    var newAsset = new Asset();
    //newAsset.id = assetIdIncrement();
    newAsset.id(assetIdIncrement());
    ...

    self.assets.push(newAsset);
}
```

This will fix your issue with the values not updating.

Edit: You're also doing the same thing in your custom bindings:

```
//viewModel.assets()[viewModel.selectedIndex()].top = position.top;
viewModel.assets()[viewModel.selectedIndex()].top(position.top);
```

Comment: Great thank you! I had to make one more change to the style binding, instead of data-bind="style { width: width+'px' ...}"  I had to change it to data-bind="style { width: width()+'px' ...}"

Comment: Right you are.  You may have other little 'gotchas' like that roaming around.  You just have to be on the look out.

Comment: Now that you have explained to me what I am doing wrong I will defiantly be on the look out not to repeat the mistake! thanks again!